# How to import Eclipse projects to IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I want to import my Eclipse projects into IntelliJ IDEA, so I went to the [IntelliJ IDEA help page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/importing-eclipse-project-to-intellij-idea.html):

> If no project is currently open in IntelliJ IDEA, click Import Project
>   on the Welcome screen. Otherwise, select File | Import Project.

Problem is there is no Import Project option on the welcome screen  and there is no Import Project option in the file menu.

Any ideas how to do this?

I checked for updates and it's telling me my 11.1.3 version is the latest, even though the help page has 12.0 in the title bar.

Comment: As far as I know IDEA does not update itself between releases - try to download latest 12 version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA 11.1 you can find the import option in the New Project dialog. You can find it at **File | New Project**.

Answer (score 54):

In **IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4** you can import a project with the following existing sources:

- **Eclipse** project (`.project`) or classpath (`.classpath`) file
- **Maven** project file (`pom.xml`)
- **Bnd/Bndtools** workspace (`workspace/cnf`)
- **Flash Builder** project file (`.project`, `*.fxp`, `*.fxpl`)
- **Gradle** build script (`*.gradle`)

Go to **File** → **New** → **Project from Existing Sources…** and a dialog will open that allows you to open one of the supported files or directories.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 - Project from Existing Sources…]

Answer (score 5):

In IntelliJ IDEA 11 you should use `File` | `New Project`, **Import project from external model**.

Also check that [Eclipse Interoperability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgpd3.png) plug-in is enabled in `Settings` | `Plugins`.

Comment: Hi, can you please confirm which eclipse plug in you are referring to? I can see plug ins such as 'eclipser' or 'eclipse code formatter' etc . Many thanks

Comment: Hi, Thank you all for your help and sorry I was away for a few days so did not reply. I was referring to eclipser plug in. My problem is i dont have a .project file it seems...?