# How to import a Eclipse Android Project to intellij 12 CE

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I can create an Android Project in intellij 12 CE.

But how to import an existing Eclipse Android project?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/importing-eclipse-projects-into-intellij-idea.html

Or check out this question:
[How to import Eclipse projects to IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876752/import-eclipse-projects-to-intellij)