# How to properly configure Eclipse project in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, import

I'm trying to import [an Eclipse project from GitHub](https://github.com/graffy76/java_fx_node_link_demo) into IntelliJ. I'm however having problems figuring out the correct way of doing that.

I'm following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876752/how-to-import-eclipse-projects-to-intellij-idea) to do the importing(I'm leaving everything on default and simply click "Next", since the answer doesn't mention anything else and I have no idea what the other stuff does), but it still doesn't work. The configuration/project structure appears to be seriously broken and I have no idea why.

More exactly, I'm currently stuck at the following screen: [image: Shows up after pressing F4] The "Problems" tag explains in more detail that both the things in red are "invalid". I tried searching for that error, but it seems that people encounter it on all different project models and build tools like Maven, Spring, or Android. None of them concern Eclipse projects and the solutions vary from issuing a bunch of commands that I don't understand somewhere to deleting this project file or another.

Since there are so many unknowns in play here, I decided to ask, rather than waste days crapshooting only to break something in my IDE or Java installation. How do I get this project to work? It's a simple local machine visual app, it shouldn't be this complicated to import it in an IDE.

Comment: I suggest that work with maven project archetype. You can import it to Netbeans, IntelliJ and Eclipse easily. To convert Eclipse project to maven project : "Right click on the project in Eclipse > Configure > Convert to Maven Project" and then you can import this project to IntelliJ and configure your dependencies easily. Hope it is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the issue is how those two libraries are defined. If you select one and then click on the edit button [image] to the right, a dialog will open and show the path to where those libraries are defined. They are likely configured to find the necessary JARs at a specific path on the (original developers) system. For example, for the `jfxrt.jar` library, maybe it is configured that the classes/binary JAR is at `C:\Program Files\Java\JavaFx\jfxrt.jar` or `C:\Users\Bob\libs\fx\jfxrt.jar`. Wherever they are defined, you either need to put the necessary JARs in that directory, or modify the config to point to the location on your system where you have the JARs. This of course may require you to download the necessary JARs.