# Running intellij JavaFx application

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

My friend recently sent me the source code for a javaFX project we are working on. However I can't run it, because it isn't configured properly. 
If i attempt to configure it as an 'Application' but it won't allow me to select the MainClass file. It was originally programmed in Eclipse.
Can someone please explain how I can get the program to run? 
In the project structure I set up Artifacts as a javaFX application but that seemed to change nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can import Eclipse projects [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32806270/4240433). If you are getting any error messages, please add them to your question